# How to give limit to Hive Query

Tags: mysql, hive

i am new to `HIVE`.i searched in Google but not got how to resolve the problem.

i want in my query limit like how it is there in mysql.

```
select * from mytable limit 0,5;
```

and next time can i do with following

```
select * from mytable limit 6,10;
```

Can any one help me how to achieve this in HIVE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this functionality is not present in Hive since the `Limit` clause chooses the outputs randomly.

You can verify this in the [Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause).

So when you execute a query like:

`select * from mytable limit 5;`

The parser actually does a `-cat` on the table file present in the Hive Warehouse and displays the result.

If you want to see the top 5 or top 10 result, you can partition your table on a logical column and then view the files in those partition.

For details on how to do partitioning on a table you can again visit the [Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-PartitionBasedQueries).